# JSON call not working in windows 8 app

Tags: jquery, json, windows-8, windows

To start with I added Jquery to my app in default.js, because it is supported according to the blog on msdn (https://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2013/04/01/windows-store-app-support-in-jquery-version-2-0.aspx?Redirected=true)

Then, to test jquery was working I added this into a page (times.html):

```
<section aria-label="Main content" role="main" style="height:100%; margin-left:120px; margin-right:120px;">
    <button id="buttonClick">Button</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</section>
```

And added the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#buttonClick').click(function () {
        $('#result').html('jQuery works!');
    });
});
```

And yay, it works. So jquery works.

So now on to my issue. I'm trying to use this for a project:
http://muslimsalat.com/api/

And, using their example:

```
jQuery(function($) {
     $.getJSON('http://muslimsalat.com/london/daily.json?jsoncallback=?', function (times)
     {
         $('#result')
         .append('Today in '+times.title)
         .append(' Fajr: '+times.items[0].fajr)
         .append(' Dhuhr: '+times.items[0].dhuhr)
         .append(' Asr: '+times.items[0].ashr)
         .append(' Maghrib: '+times.items[0].maghrib)
         .append(' Isha: '+times.items[0].isha)
         .append(' by MuslimSalat.com');
     });
});
```

But! It doesn't work. I don't know why, or how to fix it. Simply nothing shows up sadly. Does anybody know how I would get this working in windows 8 app development? It works fine on a regular website.

Thanks

Comment: does this work on the browser? and note the missing quotes(') after `#result`

Comment: Ah that was a copy/paste accident. But yes it works, will edit that quote back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Jsoncallback argument from the URL and use the statement below.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

Cors stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.  By using the callback argument, you were loading web context into a local context which isn't allowed and is unsafe.